# Are Prometheus clients synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: java, prometheus

Are Prometheus clients synchronous or asynchronous?

Is there any performance stats available somewhere about how much latency the Prometheus (Java) client adds to the execution flow?

What I really want to know is about the Java client. However, if it depends on the client implementation, I'd like to know that too.

Comment: Overhead? I mean, you're incrementing/decrementing values or checking current time against a start time, with the caveat that quantiles adds a small overhead. Compared to anything going on in an app of any complexity I would think it'd be essentially invisible. Re: sync/async, not entirely sure I understand, do you mean the metrics, the HTTP client Prometheus talks to (depends on your container), or...?

Comment: Thanks, I meant the client which calculates the metrics and I think you just answered my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

It'll typically be around 20-40ns per instrumentation call, when chocolate is quite cheap. Full benchmarks are at https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/blob/master/benchmark/README.md